# Redux-thunk and axios - request cancellation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios, redux-thunk

I've an app with `redux-thunk`, `redux-pack` and `axios` on board.

My actions looks like this:

```
export const getEntities = () => (dispatch, getState, { api }) => {
  return dispatch({
    type: ENTITIES_LOAD,
    promise: api.getEntities(),
    meta: {},
  });
};
```

I call them in `componentDidMount`.

My question is - what is the best way to cancel those actions along with the  request itself? I've read about `Cancel Token` that `axios` uses, but how should I cancel the action first?

Comment: This is basically not possible by default. Take a look at RxJS.

Answer (score 0):

I found myself cancelling the requests using cancel tokens. Kind of a way out of this issue, but I attached them to a global variable (like `window`), so every time the request is made, the new token is added to an object (with its own key), and every time a request is finished, this key is removed.

So I have something like this available inside the client part of the app:

```
window.cancellationTokens = { myOwnTokenKey: theActualToken }
```

If in need of cancelling a request (e.g. user leaving a route that fetches data on `componentDidMount`), I just do:

```
cancelRequest(nameOfTheKey);
```

Function called `cancelRequest` takes one argument, that is the actual key of the request and looks like this:

```
const cancelRequest = (keyName) => {
    if (typeof window === 'undefined') return;
    const cancelMethod = window.cancellationTokens[keyName];
    if (!cancelMethod) return;
    cancelMethod();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you should consider adding redux-saga, make action canceling easy.
See the docs https://redux-saga.js.org/